# SameFileError because of overwriting location

Tags: python, location, shutil

I have created an script that looks for words in pdf in one folder, then if it finds it moves the pdf to another folder.

```
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
import shutil

pattern = input("Enter string pattern to search: ")

basepath = Path('\hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine')

src = basepath / 'Folder 1'
dst = basepath / 'Folder 2'


for file_name in os.scandir(src):
    file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(str(src / file_name), 'rb')
    numPages = file.getNumPages()

    for i in range(0, numPages):
        pageObj = file.getPage(i)
        text = pageObj.extractText()
        
        for match in re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
            shutil.copyfile(str(src / file_name), str(dst / file_name))
```

When I run it I get error:

```
SameFileError: '\\hrdinhal\\Data\\Desktop\\Analize\\Search engine\\Folder 1\\Daily Production Summary 1.pdf' and '\\hrdinhal\\Data\\Desktop\\Analize\\Search engine\\Folder 1\\Daily Production Summary 1.pdf' are the same file
```

For some reason it takes dst and replaces it with src. Why? And how to fix it?

```
dst
Out[99]: WindowsPath('/hrdinhal/Data/Desktop/Analize/Search engine/Folder 2')
```

```
file_name
Out[100]: <DirEntry 'Daily Production Summary 1.pdf'>
```

```
dst/file_name
Out[101]: WindowsPath('/hrdinhal/Data/Desktop/Analize/Search engine/Folder 1/Daily Production Summary 1.pdf')
```

It changes Folder 2 to Folder 1!

Comment: use `print()` to see values in variables in dfferent moments - it is called "print debuging" - and maybe this helps you find where is the problem.

Comment: code seems OK. You will have to debug it on your own to see when variable change value. Your output with prefix `Out[99]:`. `Out[100]:`, `Out[101]:`  can mean that you run it in some `ipython` or `juputer` so you could run other code which changed this variable. Better put code in file and run it normally: `python script.py`

Comment: BTW: I don't understand why you use `for match`- loop to execute `copyfile`. If it find many matches then it run the same `copyfile` many times - and it makes no sense. I would rather use `if re.findall():` - to execute `copyfile` only once. But the same problem is with `for i`-loop. If it find matching patter on many pages then you will copy the same file many times. Better first sent `found = False`, next run loop and set `found = True` when it matches on any page. And after checking all pages you should do `if found: shutil.copyfile(..)` - and it will copy file only once.

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense for for loop. I don't understand your second comment. Use print() on what exactly and where?

Comment: use `print()` on every variable and in every place. But exactly `print(src)` in every place - ie. before `for file_name`, inside `for file_name`, before `for i`, inside `for i`, before `for match`, inside `for match` - this way you can see all time if `src` doesn't change value. And then you can recognize in which places it changed vlaue. And then you can check if in this place you don't assing new value to `src`, etc.. OR learn how to use readl debuger.

Comment: you could also check `file_name` - maybe it has value `../../../full/path/to/file` and then `src/../../../full/path/to/file` can gives `/full/path/to/file` and `dst/../../../full/path/to/file` can gives the same `/full/path/to/file`

Comment: ```src for file_name \hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine\Folder 1



dst for file_name \hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine\Folder 2



src/file_name for file_name \hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine\Folder 1\Daily Production Summary 1.pdf



dst/file_name for file_name \hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine\Folder 1\Daily Production Summary 1.pdf```

Comment: this is after for file_name, you can see that it changes Folder 2 of dst as soon as it gets connected to file_name

Comment: How to check for the full path for file_name?

Comment: `print(file_name)`. Maybe you will need `fil_name.name` instead of `file_name`

Comment: returns <DirEntry 'Daily Production Summary 3.pdf'>

Comment: maybe you will need `file_name.name` instead of `file_name` to get only name without fullpath.

Comment: BTW: full path - `print( file_name.path )`, only filename `print( file_name.name )`

Answer (score 0):

I find out that `file_name` keeps full path to file and this path replaces `src`, `dst` in

```
src / file_name 
dst / file_name
```

You have to get only name `file_name.name`

```
src / file_name.name
dst / file_name.name
```

---

**BTW:**

Full path

```
print( file_name.path )
```

only filename

```
print( file_name.name )
```

---

**BTW:** You copy the same file after every match but you could do it only once

Using variable `found` and copy after `for i`-loop

```
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
import shutil

pattern = input("Enter string pattern to search: ")

basepath = Path('\hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine')

src = basepath / 'Folder 1'
dst = basepath / 'Folder 2'

#print('[DEBUG] (before for file_name) src:', src)

for file_name in os.scandir(src):

    file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(str(src / file_name.name), 'rb')
    numPages = file.getNumPages()

    found = False

    # ---

    #print('[DEBUG] (before for i) src:', src)
    
    for i in range(0, numPages):
        pageObj = file.getPage(i)
        text = pageObj.extractText()

        #print('[DEBUG] (before if re) src:', src)

        if re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
            found = True
            
    # ----

    #print('[DEBUG] (before for found) src:', src)
    
    if found:
        #print('[DEBUG] (before copy) src:', src)
        shutil.copyfile(str(src / file_name.name), str(dst / file_name.name))
```

or using `break` to skip `for i`-loop after first copy

```
from pathlib import Path
import PyPDF2
import re
import os
import shutil

pattern = input("Enter string pattern to search: ")

basepath = Path('\hrdinhal\Data\Desktop\Analize\Search engine')

src = basepath / 'Folder 1'
dst = basepath / 'Folder 2'

#print('[DEBUG] (before for file_name) src:', src)

for file_name in os.scandir(src):

    #print('[DEBUG] (before pyPDF2) file_name:', file_name)

    file = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(str(src / file_name.name), 'rb')
    numPages = file.getNumPages()

    # ---

    #print('[DEBUG] (before for i) src:', src)
    
    for i in range(0, numPages):
        pageObj = file.getPage(i)
        text = pageObj.extractText()

        #print('[DEBUG] (before if re) src:', src)

        if re.findall(pattern, text, re.IGNORECASE):
            #print('[DEBUG] (before copy) src:', src)
            shutil.copyfile(str(src / file_name.name), str(dst / file_name.name))
            break # there is no need to check rest of PDF
```